My react-tinder-card can not swipe in my apllication
i am following a tutorial of making a tinder clone in react and node.js, in tutorial there is react-tinder-card which are used for swiping function, i copied all code but my cards can not being swiped in any direction. I dont know is there any problem with versions or its just in my code.I follow Ania Kubow tutorial on youtube,and i have same  code as her,but for some reason her cards can swipe,my not.Does anyone have similar problem?
My dashboard code:
import TinderCard from 'react-tinder-card'
import { useEffect,useState } from 'react'
import {useCookies} from 'react-cookie'
import ChatContainer from '../components/ChatContainer'
import axios from 'axios'



    const Dashboard = () => {
      const [user,setUser] = useState(null)
      const [genderedUsers,setGenderedUsers]=useState(null)
      const [cookies,setCookie,removeCookie] = useCookies(['user'])
      const [lastDirection, setLastDirection] = useState()

      const userId = cookies.UserId



      const getUser = async () =>{
        try{
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/user',{
                params:{ userId }
            })
            setUser(response.data)
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
      }

      const getGenderedUsers = async () =>{
        try{
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/gendered-users',{
              params:{ gender: user?.gender_interest }
            })
            setGenderedUsers(response.data)
        }catch(error){
          console.log(error)
        }
      }






      useEffect(() => {
        getUser()
        getGenderedUsers()
      },[user,genderedUsers])

      console.log(genderedUsers)

      const updateMatches = async(matchedUserId) =>{
          try{
            await axios.put('http://localhost:8000/addmatch',{
              userId,
              matchedUserId
            })
            getUser()
          }catch(error){
            console.log('error')
          }

      }




    
          
   

    const swiped = (direction, swipedUserId) => {
      
      if (direction === 'right'){
        updateMatches(swipedUserId)
      }
      setLastDirection(direction)
      }

    const outOfFrame = (name) => {
    console.log(name + ' left the screen!')
    }
    return(
    <>
      {user &&
        <div className="dashboard">
            <ChatContainer user={user} />
            <div className="swipe-container">
                <div className="card-container">

                {genderedUsers?.map((genderedUser) =>
                    <TinderCard
                     className='swipe' 
                     key={genderedUser.user_id} 
                     onSwipe={(dir) => swiped(dir, genderedUser.user_id)} 
                     onCardLeftScreen={() => outOfFrame(genderedUser.first_name)}>
                    <div style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + genderedUser.url + ')' }} className='card'>
                    <h3>{genderedUser.first_name}</h3>
                    
                    </div>
                    </TinderCard>

                )}
                <div className='swipe-info'>
                    {lastDirection ? <p>You swiped {lastDirection}</p> : <p/>}

                </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>}
    </>
    )
}
export default Dashboard


And my package.json:
{
  "name": "tinder-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-spring/web": "^9.5.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "assert": "^2.1.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.3",
    "browserify-fs": "^1.0.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "net-browserify": "^0.2.4",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-cookie": "^7.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-tinder-card": "^1.6.4",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "url": "^0.11.4",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "vm-browserify": "^1.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start:frontend": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.35.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1"
  }
}



Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Ania Kubów's tutorial is probably 12 hr+ YouTube coding bootcamp 2021.
